# Нет перевода надписи "reached" в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Походу какое-то обновление <strike>закатили</strike> вышло, и в профиле теперь под картинкой отображаются некоторые параметры (зелененьким выделено). Возможно, это было и раньше, но я чего-то не помню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так вот, слово **reached** не переведено. Более того я абсолютно уверен, что принятый перевод **людей затронул** с трудом поместится в окошко, если будет написан в строку. Возможно, конечно он введется с переносом строки, но это уж как получится.

В Традусире я не нашел этой строки.

Comment: Перенесётся: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9DCK.png. Хотя какой-нибудь перевод в одну строку смотрелся бы красивее.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно попробовать неразрывный пробел вкорячить

Comment: @Qwertiy правда, тогда [ещё хуже получается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yNbv.png).

Comment: А в одно слово тут какое-нибудь "затронуты" скорее всего подойдёт.

Comment: Завёл [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368334/339911) по невозможности перевода.

Comment: А я отсутствие перевода "Edit profile" даже не заметил!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Перевёл reached как "затронуто"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16789)
- [Edit profile как "Редактировать профиль"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16788)

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.8.13.39972

Comment: Предлагаю подредактировать на единственное число среднего рода `затронутО`, потому что: "На постановку сказуемого в форму единственного числа влияет стремление автора текста обратить внимание читателей на **пассивность подлежащего**, совместность действия действующих лиц, а также **на количество, названное в подлежащем**. Пассивность подлежащего может подчеркиваться употреблением в качестве сказуемых глаголов со значением бытия, наличия: **быть** существовать, иметься и др." У нас как раз подразумевается, что они **были** затронуты (пассив). (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=64\)

Comment: @МаксимФисман поправил