# Отсутствие переводов на странице пользователя

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

Я вообще планировал только по поводу reached вопрос создать но потом смотрю что ещё кое-где нет переводов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

за reached я не нашел здесь обсуждения, а вот то что по центру не переведено не уверен что уже не поднималось здесь. Если что кидайте дубликат :) И кст как по мне Your about me section ... как-то звучит немного кривенько, может там хоть кавычки какие-то вставить для секции?

### UPDATE

про reached нашел [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11645/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-reached-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5) если центральную секцию найду, то вопрос можно будет удалить если что.

Comment: В русском переводе кавычки добавил, а за оригинальную строку пусть англоязычные пользователи пекутся. Лучше чтоб оставили как есть, а то перевод у нас слетит :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16785

"Edit profile" [переведено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11663/176217) в составе другого вопроса.

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.8.13.39972

Comment: спасибо большое :)

Comment: @Andrew пожалуйста. Переводы, кстати, можно предлагать самостоятельно через ru.traducir.win